# R 3.6.2 incompatibility with Linux Mint 19.3

Tags: r, installation, dependencies, package, linux-mint

I know that this is no new question, rather this issue has been raised several times.
I have just switched from Linux Mint 19.1 to 19.3 (new install, not upgrade) and want to install R from scratch.
However, problems arise when I tried to follow this [repair guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031946/error-installing-r-on-ubuntu-18-broken-packages/1084755) and in the end, when attempting to run

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

The terminal replied this

```
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
> been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
> resolve the situation:
> 
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  r-base : Depends:
> r-base-core (>= 3.6.2-1disco) but it is not going to be installed
>           Depends: r-recommended (= 3.6.2-1disco) but it is not going to be installed W: Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple
> times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2 E: Unable to
> correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Now I know that this is a common problem for numerous Linux and R users, and I have read dozens of StackOverflow post regarding this issue. But the problem persists and it is for me nearly impossible to fix, because I have tried to edit the /etc/apt/sources.list and nothing changed.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Install the [dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214746/how-to-run-apt-get-install-to-install-all-dependencies) too?

Comment: @NelsonGon: That I have tried already. The point is that whenever I attempt to install a dependency, it tells me that one is not found.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem :

Use `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/` for linux mint version 19.3

and not disco (it's for the last version of Ubuntu)